# Установка старой версии GDB в Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gdb

CLion требует GDB версии 7.8.x, а в Cygwin'е максимально возможная старая версия - это 1.9.1-1. На англоязычном stackowerflow нашел порядок действий, как установить старую версию ([ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826635/clion-gdb-current-version-is-gnu-gdb-gdb-cygwin-7-10-1-1-7-10-1-supporte/36490198#36490198?newreg=f53c45106fd94b06a9561eef8202ac00)), но на 8 шаге при попытке установки из локальной папки выскакивает ошибка:

[image: ошибка]

Вот строки, на которые мне указывают:

```
[prev]
version: 7.8-1
install: x86_64/release/gdb/gdb-7.8-1.tar.xz 2491984 4C8D81984FE2CCBF92614C857737A42C4EC0C4016A5F8CF1DBC0FD117A1978BAA7A8EADD2415A6D52041A1EECBE6B4E1373BA6850DB6584869311A5E02A6E3B2
source: x86_64/release/gdb/gdb-7.8-1-src.tar.xz 17669132 A71B6886774CB004BAA7DC88ED767983A72FC94C7585BD79FF64C2BD2071C411CF0DE76584C56AA3553D9541172EAF31F1DD142A6DEDEC50C5446FF2986C6D48
```

Конкретно 11141 строка - это install:...
Объем файла в битах брал из свойств, для SHA-512 воспользовался утилитой, которая предложена там же на англоязычном сайте. Всё перепроверил, ошибок не вижу. Может, сталкивался кто с этим?

Comment: А чем вы редактировали _setup.ini_? Может, символы конца строки попортились?

Comment: Редактировал в notepad++